# Powershell Suppress Certificate Notification

Tags: powershell, rdp

I am writing a script to connect from a Windows 10 Client to a Terminal Server with the RDP-Protocoll.

The thought behind is: On these ThinClients we have about 20 RDP-Files. With about 10 of them, the password needs to be safed.

So it is quite a lot of work if you always have to save the password on every new ThinClient.

But I thought I could solve this problem with a powershell script. I just have to open the connection 1 time successfully and save the credentials and further on the credentials are saved.

I will show my code first:

```
$Server = "xx.yy.zz.xx"
$User = "DOMAIN\User"
$password = "password"

cmdkey /generic:"$Server" /user:"$User" /pass:"$password"

mstsc /v:"$Server"
```

This works so far.

But I always get the this Notification:

[image]

This is a Symbol-Picture from the Internet, as my Notification is in German. It is exactly the same, just easier to understand.

Even if I install the certificate, the notification keeps popping up.

How can I check the field with Powershell, where it says *Don't ask me again for connections to this computer*?

Comment: Try using the netbios name `laptop-7` rather then the the FQDN (meaning: no dots) for the `$Server` name or add the server domain to the trusted sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found a solution! 
There is a registry-Key generated when you Tick "Dont ask me again..."

Now i just added the necessary Registry Keys with my Powershell Script..

```
function Test-RegistryValue {

param (

 [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
 [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$Path,

[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
 [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$Value
)

try{

Get-ItemProperty -Path $Path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $Value -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
 return $true
 }

catch{

return $false

}

}


#Certificate warning turn off
$exists = Test-RegistryValue -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client' -Value 'AuthenticationLevelOverride'

if($exists -eq $False){
    reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client" /v "AuthenticationLevelOverride" /t "REG_DWORD" /d 0 /f 
}
```

Like this it works without this certificate notification!