# Powershell remote machine certificate notification

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am writing windows power shell script to connect the remote desktop machine. When execute below command in power shell am getting attached notification:

[image]

How can we handle this notification or default proceed with "Yes"?

```
cmdkey /generic:"xx.xxx.xxx.xxx" /user:"test" /pass:"pass" mstsc /v:xx.xxx.xxx.xxxx
```

Comment: You could deploy trusted certificates on all the servers...

Comment: Any windows powershell command key to accept this certificate ??

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686361/how-to-ignore-the-certificate-warning-on-remote-desktop-connection and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328972/powershell-suppress-certificate-notification

Answer (score 0):

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client" /v "AuthenticationLevelOverride" /t "REG_DWORD" /d 0 /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\LocalDevices" /v "<IP ADDRESS HERE>" /t "REG_DWORD" /d 13 /f
```

You can delete these entries after connecting